# Non differentiable loss function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, loss-function

I have a loss function that minimizes the error according to what I want the neural network to do. The problem is, that it is a nondifferentiable function. How can I handle this?

the loss function: $(1-y) \cdot log(1-p) + min((1-y)-(y \cdot log(p)))$

- $y$: target
- $p$: prediction
- `len((1-y)-(y*log(p)))` = `len(y)` = `len(p)`

I have tried to smooth the minimum, but I am not sure this is good enough. As you can see, the min operator is nondifferentiable

**How to handle a nondifferentiable loss function with Neural Networks?**

Comment: min needs at least two variables but you only have one, i.e min(x,y) or min(x,y,z)?

Comment: Can you describe what `y` and `p` are in this context?

Comment: y is the target, and p is the prediction @zachdj

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize with non-gradient based methods. The field is called [derivative-free optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization).

Local Search is one common approach for [derivative-free optimization of neural networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8993007).